# how to import databse schema in core data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I want to import database schema in my core data, i am a view based application and core data added manually.

I created a new data model , now i want to import database schema which i got in .sql file, is it possible to import that schema or I need to create all tables manually?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish.  You've created a new data model - meaning you have created your Core Data entities and relationships, etc.?  Where does the `.sql` database schema come in then?

Comment: I have only created an empty data model , now how can import database schema in that data model

Answer (score 0):

Note that Core Data is an object graph persistence framework rather than a database *per se*.  It may be subtle distinction but an important one when you consider trying to do something like what you are proposing.

While Core Data can be backed by a sqlite store, for the most part, the implementation details are opaque.  In any case you won't be able to back-port your `sql` to a Core Data model.

My recommendation is for you to decide whether Core Data is the right framework for you, in which case you should work with it by creating your entities and relationships in the model builder tool **or** alternatively, if you are keen on keeping your database schema, then looking at Cocoa wrappers around raw sqlite, such as Gus Mueller's [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

Take a look at the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001200-SW1).  Among the FAQ's is this Q/A:

> How do I use my existing SQLite database with Core Data?
>
> **You don’t.** Although Core Data supports SQLite as one of its persistent
>   store types, the database format is private. You cannot create a
>   SQLite database using native SQLite API and use it directly with Core
>   Data (nor should you manipulate an existing Core Data SQLite store
>   using native SQLite API). If you have an existing SQLite database, you
>   need to import it into a Core Data store (see “Efficiently Importing
>   Data”).