# Using SQLite in coredata in iOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I have a sqlite database designed by a DBA, i would like to use that SQLite file as persistence in core data. I dont have any idea about integrating the SQLite file with core data. Can some one help me.

Comment: I dont think you can create a coredatamodel from a Sqllite File.

Comment: See also: [how to import databse schema in core data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785131/how-to-import-databse-schema-in-core-data).

Answer (score -1):

I think the better way to approach this is to add coredata to your application. Then create a class that will parse from the sqlite to coredata. It isn't recommended to "copy, paste" the sqlite that you have with the one CD creates

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use SQL file created by DBA with CoreData. As CoreData creates it own keying system (transparent for users) to manage different tables in the CoreData model.
Nonethless you can model you CoreData model using SQL file and import the data on first time app is initialized.

Answer (score -2):

you will have to Format the sqllite File accordingly to be used for core data, have a look at these [Tutorial 1](http://ablogontech.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/using-a-pre-populated-sqlite-database-with-core-data-on-iphone-os-3-0/)  ,[Tutorial 2](http://www.readncode.com/blog/Load-SQLite-db-into-Core-Data-in-iOS-5/)